# Как открепить несколько товаров от категории в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как добавить несколько товаров в категорию прекрасно понимаю: ставим галочку в чекбоксе на нужных товарах -> действия -> изменить -> выбираем категории в которые нужно добавить -> обновить.
Но в этот раз мне нужно осуществить обратное, мне нужно не добавить товары к категории, а открепить от той категории в которой они закреплены.
Проблема в том что товаров овер 1500, и заходить на каждую страницу редактирования товара не лучшая идея...
Существуют способы это быстро сделать?

Comment: Надо открепить 1500, или всего 1500?

Comment: Не знаю чем это влияет на суть вопроса, открепить 1500, всего товаров куда больше.
Даже когда товаров 10-15 уже становится неудобно, заходить на каждую страницу изменения, и снимать галочки, такое себе...

Comment: Из текста вопроса непонятно, сколько надо открепить. Если бы открепить надо было 20-50 из 1500, то в админке есть быстрое редактирование, на странице /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product. Но кликать там 1500 - не вариант. Можно программно, но по каким признакам отобрать товары, подлежащие откреплению?

Comment: Я думал попробовать удалить категорию, но в этой категории есть товары, которые откреплять нельзя, они должны остаться.

Comment: Я знаю что есть быстрое редактирование, но трабл в том что оно не предлагает такой функции, там можно только добавить выбранные товары в категорию а не наоборот, либо я тупой и чего-то не заметил. Если я всетаки тупой, напишите пожалуйста как это сделать и что я не заметил.
Скинул пример, сайт не тот, но суть прекрасно отражает...

Comment: Там не снять категорию, да. Только программно.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это я и хотел узнать!
Разработчикам woocommerce пора задуматься о такой функции)

Comment: Искать плагин в репо по ключам типа "bulk edit". Для стандартных рубрик их хватает, а вот какой работает с WC я не в курсе.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при помощи плагина BEAR https://bulk-editor.com/video#video_2502

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/840679)